# How to show debugger in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to show this in laravel 5.4?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar 2.4`

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/2.4

And follow the installation instructions

Then, make sure the debug is enabled with `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file